# Update element on button click is not working

Tags: vue.js

I'm new using Vuejs so I have a simple page with an input and button like

```
<input type="text" value="10" v-model="model.rowsPerPage"> 
<button @click="setNewValue()"> </button>


<script lang="ts">
import { useContact } from '@/composition/useContact'
import { ContactModel } from '@/services/modules/contact/contact'
import { defineComponent, reactive } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Contact',

  setup() {
    const model = reactive<ContactModel>({
      pageNumber: 1,
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      searchBy: null,
      staringDate: null,
      endingDate: null,
    })

    const {
      data: contactList,
      totalItems: totalItems,
      isLoading: isLoading,
      error: error,
    } = useContact(model)

    return {
      contactList,
      model,
      isLoading,
      totalItems,
      error,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setNewValue() {
      model.rowsPerPage = 20
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

So what I want to do, is update the input value by 10 if the button is clicked, so as you can see I add a method at the end of the script

```
methods: {
        setNewValue() {
          model.rowsPerPage = 20
        },
      },
```

But it throws me an error:

> Cannot find name model

Why I can't access to const model declared at the top of script? How can I solve this? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the methods you need to reference the "this" object to have access to what's returned in data or setup
but if you're using vue 3 with the composition api, you can simply define the function inside setup and return it, your template will then have access to it
(also, I think you should keep your component html inside a template tag)

Comment: Great I'm using Vue 3 so I just created function inside setup as:   `function setNewValue() {
      model.rowsPerPage = 20
    }` Thanks!